# In a stable sorting algorithm with 2 same values, why does the first value from the original array must come in first in the sorted array?

Tags: algorithm

It is something I don't understand because if the array is Un-sorted it means that the position of any element in the array does not matter when sorting the array only the key by which you sort the array should be considered if there are two keys with the same value, why does the default return to the original array to check where was its position before the sorting? is it like that just because that is the only possibility it has?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Is there any possibilities for you to show some example array, unsorted and then sorted, and point out what values you're wondering about in that array? That would be a good start anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the content of this post. But the answer to the question in the topic is "because that's the definition of stable"

Comment: for example a list with a key value that has 'x' and 'y' : [1,2| 1,3| 4,2| 3,6]
and we want to sort this by 'x', we have 1,2 and 1,3 meaning the same value, why does a stable algorithm look at the original list to determine the position of the duplicate values in the sorted array not by value but by the position they had in the unsorted array?

Answer (score 5):

I assume your question is "why do you want stability in a sorting algorithm?", otherwise check @Sopel's comment.

Some sorting algorithms are stable by nature like Insertion sort, Merge Sort, Bubble Sort, etc. And some sorting algorithms are not, like Heap Sort, Quick Sort, etc. Stability is a property in sorting algorithms that is required for some applications.

Consider the following example: you want to sort people by `last_name` and if the `last_name` is identical sort them by `first_name` (like in a telephone book). One way to achieve this, is by sorting the elements by `first_name` and afterwards use a stable sorting algorithm to sort by `last_name`. This will only give you the correct result if the second sorting is stable ensuring that people with the same `last_name` are still sorted by their `first_name` from the initial sorting.

Comment: In the telephone book application you wold sort once and use a Comperator that considers first and last name. But you are totally right about the idea. The stable sorting is especially important if you if the you don't know the combinations and priority of different attributes to sort by upfront.

Comment: @MrSmith42 fair point. Should have mentioned that the example is just for illustration purposes and not the most efficient solution.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Why? SaiBot's way could easily be faster.

Comment: If we count calls to the two combined comparators separately, sorting with the combined comparators should still take fewer comparisons than double-sorting, because sometimes/often the second comparator doesn't need to be called. The overhead of calling a chained comparator could in principle be significant, but I would assume in most cases double-sorting is a bit slower. I have only tested this once, in Python, the chained comparator was ~5% faster in the case I tested, so in other circumstances it could well be slower for whatever reason.

Comment: @kaya3 With chained comparator in Python, are you talking about Python 2? I just tried (yet again, not the first time) the typical Python 3 way, and the two sorts were (yet again) *faster* than the single sort, by about factor 1.4: https://repl.it/repls/CourageousSilkyDifferences

Comment: @HeapOverflow I mean in Python 3 done the way in your example, using a key function returning a tuple, so that the second component is the fallback. I realise that "chained comparator" isn't really what that is, I just meant it as a shorthand, so sorry if that wasn't clear. Let me see if I can find the case I was testing it with.

Comment: The case I'm thinking of had significantly shorter lists, so the performance difference (which was a small proportion anyway) in absolute terms was negligible for a single sort anyway. It looks like for longer lists the difference is bigger and consistent in favour of sorting twice, and I think you are right that it's the tuples that are the issue.

Comment: @kaya3 Scratch my (now deleted) comment about `itemgetter` changing things much. I messed up badly and in reality it barely changes things at all.

Comment: @kaya3 Tried with 1000 elements instead of a million now, and with itemgetter as well. Sorting twice was still faster by about factor 1.35: https://repl.it/repls/HauntingGreatRegression

Comment: Yeah, I mean much shorter lists - say, 10 elements. Use-case could be e.g. a dictionary whose keys are sorted tuples, so that the order of the key's components doesn't matter but the frequency of repeated components does (hence frozenset isn't applicable). Double-sorting for n=10 is 5-10% slower, by my test and using your timing code; I hadn't realised the ratio was so dependent on the list size, but I guess it should have been obvious not to extrapolate.

Answer (score 1):

> *why does a stable algorithm look at the original list to determine the position of the duplicate values in the sorted array not by value but by the position they had in the unsorted array?*

You are assuming that a sorting algorithm would have to do this in order to be stable. But that is not the case.

---

Consider bubble sort, for example. Bubble sort only ever swaps **adjacent** elements, and it only swaps them if they are currently out of order. Now imagine we have two elements in the array with equal keys:

```
[..., 8♦, ..., ..., ..., 8♥, ...]
```

Bubble sort will swap 8♦ to the right and/or it will swap 8♥ to the left. But it only ever swaps them one space at a time. So after a some swaps they end up being adjacent:

```
[..., ..., ..., 8♦, 8♥, ..., ...]
```

And then they will stay adjacent (except while temporarily swapping a value with a larger key past both of them), and they will **never** be swapped with each other, because they are not out of order relative to each other. So, bubble sort will leave them in their original relative order.

Note that this works **without** comparing the original indices; if 8♦ is to the left of 8♥, then it stays to the left of 8♥ simply because the algorithm won't swap them with each other. This means that bubble sort is *naturally* stable without keeping track of the original array indices or looking them up.

---

In practice, we call a sorting algorithm "stable" if it's *naturally* stable, without having to use the original indices as a tie-breaker. The technique of keeping track of the original array indices is used when you want to do a stable sort using an *unstable* sorting algorithm; an algorithm is stable if you don't need to use that technique.